# Ruby datetime attribute values not saving in SQLite DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, datetime

I'm trying to save Order objects with 'sale_price' (float) and 'order_date' (datetime) attributes to a SQLite DB. Everything in the logs makes it look as though both attribute types are saved properly for each Order object. However, when I check the DB, all of the Order objects 'order_date' attributes are nil. Here's the code:

```
response["orders"].each do |n|

        balance = n["balance"]

        sale_price = balance.to_f

        order_date = n["created_date"]

        order = Order.new(sale_price: sale_price, order_date: order_date)

        if Order.where(order_date: order_date).exists?

            puts "That order already exists in the DB"

        else

            if (order.sale_price || order.order_date) != nil 

                order.save

            else
                p "The sale price is nil"
            end

        end     

    end
```

Here's what a sample transaction looks like in the logs:

```
    Order Exists (0.9ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."order_date" = '2013-12-06T15:53:36.424Z' LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "orders" ("created_at", "order_date", "sale_price", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Tue, 27 May 2014 22:59:02 UTC +00:00], ["order_date", Fri, 06 Dec 2013 15:53:36 UTC +00:00], ["sale_price", 20548.0], ["updated_at", Tue, 27 May 2014 22:59:02 UTC +00:00]]
   (3.1ms)  commit transaction
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you make a puts of `order.sale_price` and `order.order_date` before saving and show what's logging?

Comment: Here you go: 20828.0
2014-05-07 16:28:34 UTC

Comment: Are all the other attributes what you expect them to be?  Are you absolutely sure you're looking at the right db file? (check your database.yml to be sure)

Comment: Yes. Everything else is fine except the order_date attribute value is nil for all entries. Here's a look from console: [#<Order id: 1, created_at: "2014-05-27 21:54:15", updated_at: "2014-05-27 21:54:15", sale_price: 20828.0, order_date: nil>

Comment: Hmmm... And what's your order_date column type? Perhaps you're having a type error, so your data is not being assigned correctly. Check that you've set timestamp type in order_date.

Comment: OK, so I changed the type to 'timestamp' instead of 'datetime', and the 'order_date' values are still nil. [#<Order id: 1, created_at: "2014-05-27 21:54:15", updated_at: "2014-05-27 21:54:15", sale_price: 20828.0, order_date: nil>

Comment: If you call `order.save!` instead of `order.save` does it fail?

Comment: Can you share the version of rails and sqlite you're using?

Comment: When I call order.sale!, it's the same story. In the logs, it looks like everything is good, but then when I check the values for all 'order_date' attributes are still nil

Comment: I'm using Rails 4.0.0 with sqlite3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(From the John W mentioned in @dougiebuckets answer) I think what was most likely happening (and why deleting your sqlite db file worked) is that you were looking at the first records created. Since you added the order_date field to Order in a later migration, those first records would have a nil value for order_date since that field didn't exist when they were created.

I also cheated because I had access to @dougiebuckets source code. :) But this is my first SO answer, so cut me some slack. :D

Answer (score 1):

Deleting 'development.sqlite3' and re-running my migrations fixed it (Thanks John W.)

It looks like I had already saved all of the Order objects before adding the 'order_date' attribute, so when I saved them again w/ the 'order_date' attribute I could only see the initial Order objects that didn't have it from the original save in the console. Oops.